# Equivalent of += for prefixing

Tags: c#, string

Is there a bit of syntactic sugar for prefixing data to the beginning of a string in a similar way to how += appends to a string?

Comment: Can't you just call += with the arguments reversed?  I'm not familiar with C# but that would work in Java.

Comment: that would post append the first string to the second, not prefix the second string in froint of the first. The result would be the same string, but in the wrong variable

Comment: @l82Much: Surely you'd need to do something like: s = "Prepend" += s;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use:

```
x = "prefix" + x;
```

There's no compound assignment operator that does this.

Comment: Thanks Jon (Tony). I've taken your comments below into account also.

Answer (score 17):

```
sorry = "nope, " + sorry;
```

Answer (score 7):

You could always write an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions{

    public static string Prefix(this string str, string prefix){
        return prefix + str;
    }

}

var newString = "Bean".Prefix("Mr. ");
```

It's not syntactic sugar, but easy nonetheless. Although it is not really any simpler than what has already been suggested.

Answer (score 7):

There is no =+ operator in C#, but thankfully OO comes to the rescue here:

```
string value = "Jamie";
value = value.Insert(0, "Hi ");
```

For more info on string.Insert:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx

I would agree that a = b + a seems the most sensible answer here. It reads much better than using string.Insert that's for sure.

Comment: Cheers Nick. I decided to go with the String.Concat method in the end.

Answer (score 0):

These are methods from the FCL that can be used to merge strings, without having to use any concatenation operator. The + and += operators are prone to using a lot of memory when called repeatedly (i.e. a loop) because of the nature of strings and temp strings created. (**Edit:** As pointed out in comments, String.Format is often not an efficient solution either)

It's more of a syntactic alternative than sugar.

```
string full = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "prefix", "main string", "last string");
```

^ More info on [String.Format at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx).

**Edit:** Just for two strings:

```
string result = string.Concat("prefix", "last part");
```

^ More info on [String.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx).

Comment: Using String.Format repeatedly would be just as problematic. Using String.Concat is more efficient than using String.Format, to just concatenate strings. Concatenation in a loop is likely to be better using a StringBuilder, not String.Format.

Comment: Using String.Format this way is very inefficient.  The CPU use is much worse, and it also still wastes RAM.  You want String.Concat instead:  string full = String.Concat("prefix", "main string", "last string").  You can also pass String.Concat a string[] that you built in a loop (eg you can build a List<string>, then ToArray() it).  This results in the very least memory usage of all because it allocates only the space needed to store the resulting string.  Both "+" and String.Format on average allocate about 30% more RAM than needed.  This is important only when dealing with large strings.